# Check first character of string is uppercase with a switch statement

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I made code that will check is that the first letter is uppercase. There's one error, it says.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

This code works in other languages like PAWN and C++/C. Why it doesn't work in jQuery?

```
switch(_ime[0])
{
    case 'A' .. 'Z': { }
    default: return -2;
}
```

Comment: jquery isnt a language, it is a framework written for javascript. Much like how .Net isnt a langauge, but a framework for c#/vb

Comment: It doesn't work because it isn't valid JavaScript. It's as simple as that. You can't expect one language's constructs or syntactical niceties to transfer over to another language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`..` is not valid syntax in Javascript. If you want to do this you would need to include each case manually:

```
switch(_ime[0]) {
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    // and every other letter...
    case 'Z':
        console.log('A to Z');
        break;
    default: 
        return -2;
}
```

Alternatively you could check that the charCode for the first character is between `65` and `90` (ie. `A` and `Z`):

```
var firstCharcode = _ime.charCodeAt(0);
if (firstCharCode >= 65 && firstCharCode <= 90) {
    console.log('capital first');
} else {
    return -2;
}
```

Comment: Does jQuery has function which I can use to check does text starts with uppercase letter?

Comment: No. jQuery is primarily used for amending the DOM. Javascript provides all underlying functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that will check is that the first letter is uppercase.

```
/^[A-Z]/.test(_ime)
```